# When adding a new product variation type no catalog options appear

Tags: 7, commerce

I have installed the Commerce Kickstart installation profile and I am currently experimenting with it. The main problem I face is when adding a new product variation type and trying to create a new product using it, the vertical TAB where you select the product catalog, instead of this :

[image: Product Catalog with taxonomy]

I get this :

[image: Empty product catalog options]

So far I have tried reindexing and checking the views filters without finding the root cause of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that when adding a new *Product Variation*, a new content type linked to this variation is automagically created with the corresponding representations.

All I had to do is adding the Catalog term reference to the linked content type.

Comment: Hi could you please explain this in more detail, as i am stuck at this problem too. and am desperate for some help. many thanks DrGaud

Comment: Just go to the new content type that is created and add the term reference field that link to the catalog. In the end it's just adding some new fields to a content type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to again add a new term references field to your new content type on which you have added new product variations.
In this way you will see the product catalog for your content.